# custom tooltip broken when add transform scale transition

Tags: css, tooltip, css-transforms

If I remove `scale` in `transform` from line 18 and 48 *(leave `translateY` only)*, the code works, but not decent. I want to add `scale` transition to make the transition smoother, but leads to the rectangle and the tooltip not going well along together. How to fix this?

```css
.tooltip {
  display: block;
  background: #F24B5B;
  color: white;
  margin: 5em auto;
  padding: 1em 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 13em;
  position: relative;

  --rec-size: .3em;
  --half-rec-size: calc( var(--rec-size) / 2 )
}
.tooltip::before,
.tooltip::after {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(.5) translateY(1em);
  transform-origin: center bottom;
  transition: 
    opacity .3s ease-out, 
    transform .15s ease-out
    ;
}
.tooltip::after {
  content: '';
  border: var(--rec-size) solid #0000;
}
.tooltip::before {
  content: attr(title);
  width: 80%;
  line-height: 2em;
  border-radius: .2em;
  background: #000b;
}
.tooltip.top::before {
  bottom: calc( 100% + var(--rec-size) );
  left: 10%;  
}
.tooltip.top::after {
  border-top: var(--rec-size) solid #000b;
  bottom: calc( 100% - var(--rec-size) );
  left: calc( 50% - var(--half-rec-size) );
}
.tooltip:hover::before,
.tooltip:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1) translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip top" title="Tooltip on top!">
  Hover over me
</div>
```

Comment: try `transform-origin: center 150%;` instead of `transform-origin: center bottom;`, or the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.tooltip {
  display: block;
  background: #F24B5B;
  color: white;
  margin: 5em auto;
  padding: 1em 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 13em;
  position: relative;

  --rec-size: .3em;
  --half-rec-size: calc( var(--rec-size) / 2 )
}
.tooltip::before,
.tooltip::after {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(.5) translateY(1em);
  transform-origin: center bottom;
  transition: 
    opacity .3s ease-out, 
    transform .15s ease-out
    ;
}

.tooltip::after {
  transform: translateY(0.5em);
}

.tooltip::after {
  content: '';
  border: var(--rec-size) solid #0000;
}
.tooltip::before {
  content: attr(title);
  width: 80%;
  line-height: 2em;
  border-radius: .2em;
  background: #000b;
}
.tooltip.top::before {
  bottom: calc( 100% + var(--rec-size) );
  left: 10%;  
}
.tooltip.top::after {
  border-top: var(--rec-size) solid #000b;
  bottom: calc( 100% - var(--rec-size) );
  left: calc( 50% - var(--half-rec-size) );
}
.tooltip:hover::before,
.tooltip:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1) translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip top" title="Tooltip on top!">
  Hover over me
</div>
```

::after and ::before set a different translateY

```
.tooltip::after {
  transform: translateY(0.5em);
}
```

Or like the one above

```
.tooltip::after,.tooltip::before {
  transform-origin: center 140%;
}
```

Comment: Is this adjusting around and the result happen or any method?

Comment: @LarryN Or the above transform-origin: center 140%;

Comment: Thank you, I just wonder how did you come with the solution, by tweaking around?

Comment: @LarryN It's to understand that scale is based on the origin scaling principle.::after and ::before It's based on different transform-origins